# How to deal with a generating function with a finite amount of terms?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have been given the following recurrence relation:

$b_{n} = (−1)^{n}(n + 1)a_{0} + (−1)^{n−1}(n)a_1 + · · · + (−1)(2)a_{n−1} + a_n $

I am trying to find a generating function for $b_{n}$ in terms of the generating function for $a_{n}$

I get the pattern for the sequence is $-1^{n}(n+1),-1^{n-1}(n), -1^{n-2}(n-1) \dots -1^{n-(n-1)}(2), -1^{n-n}(1)$

However, the thing that confuses me is how I would index this sequence. Is there a way of indexing 'backwards', such that the sum goes from n to zero. For example:

$\sum_{k=n}^{0} = ((k+1)(-1)^{k})a_k\ x^{n-k}$

However, I have no idea how I would be able to express this in closed form, let alone whether it is possible. and as such I was wondering whether someone could explain what direction I could take.

I have also thought of modifying the sequence to make it so that:

$\frac{b_{n}}{g(n)} = a_{n}$ where $g(n) = \frac{1}{1+n} + \frac{2}{1-n}$ which I believe is the closed form expression for the sequence 1,-1,1,-1,1.

However, this still leaves me with the problem of finding the sequence for $a_{n}$ which would still be $(n+1)a_{0} + (n)a_{1} + \dots + (2)a_{n-1} + (1)a_{n}$

I am confused as to whether the above sequence is finite or infinite, as such I was wondering whether someone could explain what direction I could take from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The suggested writing $\sum_{k=n}^0$ is not helpful, since a sum is defined to be zero when the upper limit is less than the lower limit. A way to cope with it is addressed in my answer at (2).

Answer (score 2):

We consider a generating function $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and are looking for a generating function $B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ with
\begin{align*}
b_n&=(-1)^n(n+1)a_0+(-1)^{n-1}na_1+\cdots -2a_{n-1}+a_n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(n+1-k) a_k\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We apply the *[Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)*. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^n]A(z)=a_n
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1):
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b_n}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(n+1-k) a_k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}(k+1) a_{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\left([z^k]\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\right)\left([z^{n-k}]A(z)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^n]\frac{1}{(1+z)^{2}}A(z)}
> \end{align*}
>   and conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B(z)=\frac{A(z)}{(1+z)^2}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we change the order of summation by replacing the index $k$ with $n-k$.
- In (3) we use the series representation
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(k+1)z^k=\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
  \end{align*}
  and apply the *Cauchy product formula*
  \begin{align*}
  Q(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty q_kz^k,\qquad R(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty r_jz^j\\
  Q(t)R(t)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+j=n}\atop{k,j\geq 0}}q_kr_j\right)t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n q_k r_{n-k}\right)t^n\\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \left([z^k]Q(z)\right)\left([z^{n-k}]R(z)\right)t^n
  \end{align*}